# How can I insert new lines into a range in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make an excel sheet that captures a username of whoever edited a cell (for an inventory system). I have it set it up so that every time an entry is created, it will add a row underneath. I have that set up alright, but I want to get fancier. Since this is a daily report, I'd like to add a button that clears/resets the range. For reference, my first entry row is a/b8, the "name" is printed to c, and it enters down. This is what I have (working) that adds the row, but could I add a function that extends a range from the first row to the most recently edited, so then I can just reset the range?

I'd like to go from this

```
order:    cartons:    user Id:
36546        1           123
89098        2           456
98498        4           789
total boxes: 7
```

to this:

```
order:    cartons:    user Id:

total boxes: 0
```

Thanks in advance!

```
  If Target.Row = [TotalVal].Row - 1 Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
      [TotalVal].EntireRow.Insert
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
```

Comment: You can use `.Find` to search for total boxes `.Range("A:A").Find("total boxes:", lookat:xlwhole).Offset(-1)` to get the row above which, if I understand correctly, would be the last entered order. If that doesn't work, please make your question more clear and / or show more clear screen shot of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to clear out the numbers on a daily basis?  Assuming you're based in the top left:

```
Sub ClearNumbers()

dim wsh as Worksheet

set wsh = thisworkbook.worksheets(1) 'or whatever worksheet it actually is

while isnumeric(wsh.cells(2, 1))
    wsh.rows(2).delete
wend

wsh.rows(2).insert
End Sub
```

Assuming all those gaps are different cells.

Comment: Something like that might work. Yes, I'm trying to make a range that expands every time you add a row, that I can clear out at the end of the day and moves the "Total" row up again instead of leaving it shoved down.

Comment: *I'm trying to make a range that expands every time you add a row* - see [Dynamic Named Ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html#Dynamic). Then just delete the entire rows of that range with VB code at day's end.